# JQuery Sortable ConnectWith don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two sortable lists. I want to connect this lists so I will be able to move items from one list to another in both directions. I use sortable connectWith, but still I cant move list  items from one to another list.

Also I'm able to move items from one place to another but in the same list.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="category-container" data-id="1"> 
    <div class="category-header" data-id="1"> 
    </div>
    <ul class="list-items ui-sortable">
        <li class="item" data-id="3">
        <li class="item" data-id="43">
        <li class="item" data-id="28">
        <li class="item" data-id="24">
        <li class="item" data-id="21">
        <li class="item new" data-id="0">
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="category-container" data-id="2">
    <div class="category-header" data-id="2"> 
    </div>
    <ul class="list-items ui-sortable">
        <li class="item" data-id="17">
        <li class="item" data-id="8">
        <li class="item" data-id="9">
        <li class="item new" data-id="0">
    </ul>
</div>
```

And JQuery:

```
 $(".list-items").sortable({
            connectWith: '.list-items',
            items: "li:not(.item.new)",
            placeholder: 'place-holder',
            scroll: false,
            tolerance: "pointer"
}).disableSelection();
```

I cant find out what is the problem.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured out.

The problem was the list float property. Sortable connectWith dont work with css float.

[Sortable connectWith Bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4551)

Comment: Thanks that saved me some time too. In my case I had nested lists side by side which meant the ul > li's had to be floated. The way to get round it is to cancel the inheritance by an extra rule: `ul > li > ul > li {float:none;}.` Then it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I just would like to share something that I just realized and maybe can help somebody.

The **element which will receive an element** (div/ul) from another list/table **must have enough "space" to receive** (width and height) and display the new element.

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 1):

Well, for me the list just works as expected.. Check this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/GSA2A/2/

Also you should write valid html, close your tags at least.. Most browsers can handle missing closed li-elements depending on which doctype you are using.

You can also use:

```
$('#list1, list2').sortable({.......
```

Looks better to me and more logical to have the sortable function used on id's and the connectWith on a class combining those lists.

Comment: I'm adding lists dinamically and becouse of that I'm using class selector, and the HTML code is copied from firebug (li > items) :). Maybe the problem is somewhere else in my application. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: well, you should add some of your code then. as long as the sortable is applied after the content was added it should work fine. Also you might have a look at the refresh method for dynamic lists http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Sortable#method-refresh

Comment: `list2` ... do you mean `#list2` ? And why use *N* IDs if you can simply use one class :) That's what classes are for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assigning both ul to an id and in jQuery file I get both id with and use sortable();
apply different parameters and it's working for me you can use this code I'm using jquery-3.1.1.js, you try to add containment:'document'

```js
$('#list, #thi').sortable({
  containment: 'document',
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  revert: true,
  opacity: 0.4,
  connectWith: '#list,#thi',
  update: function() {
    // alert('f');
    content = $(this).text();
    $('#fdk').text(content);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>School</li>
  <li>Name</li>
  <li>Roll</li>
</ul>
<ul id="thi">
  <li>School</li>
  <li>Name</li>
  <li>Roll</li>
</ul>

<div id="fdk">
</div>
```